# Convert RDD List to RDD of individual element in spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a input rdd (`JavaRDD<List<String>>`) and i want to convert it to `JavaRDD<String>` as output. 
Each element of input RDD list should become a individual element in output rdd.

how to achieve it in java?

```
JavaRDD<List<String>> input; //suppose rdd length is 2
input.saveAsTextFile(...)
```

output:

> [a,b] 
>  [c,d]

what i want:

> a
>  b 
> c 
> d

Comment: no, flatmap would not work because it will have again list of elements and when i store it will not store each element in separate line. my input RDD is equally output of flatmap.

Comment: You shouldn't be so rude, I was trying to help. BTW, I didn't down vote you if that is what you thought. However, this is what you want but in lovely `Scala`. [A published notebook](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/2485090270202665/382256499319578/8589256059752547/latest.html)

Comment: I am new to spark and my apologies if my comment sounds rude.

Comment: I want to call parallelize function on top of rdd. how to do that?

Comment: RDDs are already parallelized !!!

Comment: the workaround i have posted in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a workaround using below code snippet:

Concat each element of list with separator `'\n'` then save rdd using standard spark API.

```
inputRdd.map(new Function<List<String>, String>() {
           @Override
           public String call(List<String> scores) throws Exception {
               int size = scores.size();
               StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
               for (int i=0; i <size;i++){
                   sb.append(scores.get(i));
                   if(i!=size-1){
                        sb.append("\n");
                    }
               }
               return sb.toString();
           }
       }).saveAsTextFile("/tmp/data"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert it into a DataFrame and use Explode  UDF function.

Answer (score 0):

If the rdd type is `RDD[List[String]]`, you can just do this:

`val newrdd = rdd.flatmap(line => line)`

Each of the elements will be a new line in the new rdd.

Answer (score -1):

below will solve your problem

```
 var conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("test")
            .setMaster("local[1]")
            .setExecutorEnv("executor-cores", "2")
 var sc = new SparkContext(conf)
 val a = sc.parallelize(Array(List("a", "b"), List("c", "d")))  
 a.flatMap(x => x).foreach(println)
```

**output :**

> a
>  
>   b 
>   c 
>   d

Comment: my dataset size is very huge and i want to save rdd to file.

Comment: from flatpMap function can i write each record to file ?