# Convert JavaRDD<List<SomeClass>> to JavaRDD<SomeClass>

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd, flatmap

I have a JavaRDD of a list of class objects.  I want to flatten it to a JaveRDD of class objects such that
JavaRDD<{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7}> goes to JavaRDD<1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7>

in this post
[Convert RDD List to RDD of individual element in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38985651/convert-rdd-list-to-rdd-of-individual-element-in-spark)
one solution is

```
val newrdd = rdd.flatmap(line => line)
```

however, line=>line is scala (I think)
I tried

```
rdd.flatmap(line-> line)
```

and it gives and error

"no instance(s) of type variable(s) U exist so that List conforms to Iterator "

Comment: Please show your complete code. How did you get RDD to hold a list in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/function/FlatMapFunction.html) you pass to [`flatMap`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDD.html#flatMap(org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FlatMapFunction)) should return a `java.util.Iterator<T>`, not a `List<T>`. It should suffice to do this:

```
JavaRDD<SomeClass> newRdd = rdd.flatMap(List::iterator);
```